# How to open tiff images in PDFTron

Tags: tiff, pdftron

I want to open `tiff` images in the [pdftron webviewer](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/).I am able to open `pdf` files `jpeg`,`PNG` images and `MS Docs` as well. But for tiff images, I am unable to open. I want to open tiff images using the `AddImageTest.js` source code. How to utilize this source code to open tiff images in PDFTron Webviewer in `Angular7.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this page which is a modified version of the AddImageTest code to view a tiff file https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/faq/load-tiff/

The key part is that you can call loadDocument and pass in the PDFDoc object to display in the viewer.

Comment: Its working fine if I use this code inside the .then of web Viewer object.But As per requirement from the list of documents which are of different types, one of them is TIFF/TIF.If I click on that that tiff image is being passed to this function to convert and display the TIFF/TIF image.But Its giving no response.Can you please help in this scenario.